# Sistema de login único

Tags: php, html, login

Como criar um sistema de *login único* em **PHP**? Que dê acesso à vários sites para o usuário, sem precisar fazer o login em cada site. Como por exemplo o Google, que com um único login, você usa o Google e o YouTube.

Comment: Essa pergunta é muito ampla.... existem varias formas de se fazer, utilizando frameworks(zend, cake, laravel, joomla, entre muitos outros), ou php puro, utilizando mais recursos front-end, como storage em js, ou mais back-end, deixando mais a conta do servidor, assim como cadastrado usuários, validando dados e etc....

A rede não funciona assim, monte o escopo do seu projeto, se surgir alguma duvida em ferramentas ou funções especificas na construção, ai sim se torna mais cabível....

Comment: Acho válido o que o colega citou acima. De todo modo, algo parecido com que o que você citou me lembrou o [Oauth](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Oauth), dá uma pesquisada.

Comment: @WilliamNovak Obrigado

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Eu desejaria criar esse sistema em PHP puro, para estudo!

Comment: Melhor compreendendo a sua pergunta, depois que editou, creio que o Oauth não é uma solução nem mesmo uma base de estudo no seu caso, ainda mais devido a complexidade dele. No seu caso, seria um trabalho simples trabalhar com _session_ desde que elas fossem salvas no mesmo lugar. Dá uma olhada aqui [session.configuration](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php).

Comment: @WilliamNovak Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualquer sessão criada, por padrão é criado um cookie no navegador chamado `PHPSESSID` que é salvo o nome da sessão (em hash) criado pelo seu código na pasta temporária do servidor.

Você pode acessar esse cookie usando `session_get_cookie_params()` antes do `session_start()` que irá mostrar alguns parâmetros:

```
Array
(
[lifetime] => 0 
[path] => /
[domain] => 
[secure] => 
[httponly] => 
)
```

o `[lifetime] => 0` indica que quando o navegador for fechado o cookie irá desaparecer e assim a sessão será fechada.

Pensando desta maneira, na qual sempre que uma sessão é aberta um cookie é criado. Não vejo o porque de não usar cookies para este caso:

- Criar um cookie com um nome definido para que os outros sites possam acessar.
- Fazer o valor do cookie ser uma chave/token (hash) que você cria sempre que o usuário fizer o login em um dos sites participantes.
- Essa hash é salva no banco de dados que todos os sites participantes tem acesso.
- Fazer uma verificação no db (usuário / chave / cookie ) cada vez que o ele acessa algo em qualquer um dos sites para verificar a identidade deste usuário ou loga-lo automaticamente. Você pode usar ip da máquina também.

Assim ele fará apenas um login em qualquer um dos sites.

Claro que existe toda uma segurança envolvida que você terá que realizar.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!